# How do I get Maven to check if source code has changed before deciding a dependency is resolved?

Tags: maven, dependencies

Maven does a lot of neat things, but I find my self having to "mvn clean" far more often than I would like.  It quits doing its dependency resolution/up-to-date check as soon as it finds the jar file for foo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT in my local repository, even if the source code for that jar has changed.  Having to purge **everything** (or go through each of the affected directories myself) every time I make a change in the next directory over is getting old.

I want a way to flag my intra-project module dependencies to tell Maven "Hey, this is built locally so don't use the foo.jar from ~/.m2 until you've checked that foo's sources haven't changed and rebuilt it if necessary."  This is way easy in Ant, but I haven't figured out the Maven way to to it.

Comment: I've got the impression you should describe your setup a little more in detail, cause i coming up that you're doing things wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi module build that is set up correctly it will just do what you want fine. This is referred to a reactor build. It just depends a bit on your setup.

If you have separate projects it will always get its dependencies from the local repo so you will have to make sure they get there by building them. You can either do that manually or create a multi module pom that ties things together.

Comment: I went back to play with the reactor thing again because I didn't have much luck with it the first time.  I have found that if I **add** a new class, it behaves the way I'd expect: it compiles only the new file and rebuilds the jar.  However, if I modify an existing class, it says "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date", which is wrong.

Comment: What version of Maven are you using? Try with a 3x version.. lots of improvements related to reactor builds and more are in it..

Comment: It turns out that if I go have a cup of coffee and come back, the modified class gets picked up by the reactor.  There seems to be some kind of cool-down on the timestamp reader or something.  A minute or so seems to be enough, but a couple seconds is not.

Comment: thats weird and should not happen. Might want to file a bug or ask on the maven dev list..

Comment: At least I'm not crazy.  Maybe it's a weird Mac filesystem interaction or something.  I'll check the dev list and bug system as you suggest.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The project which creates the foo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT should do a

```
   mvn deploy
```

everytime it has changed something. And than you will be able to get the changes simply by doing an other mvn clean compile in the project which use the foo-0.1.0-SNAPTSHOT as dependency.